# How do you compile variables and still use them individually?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, openpyxl, pycel

TL;DR - trying to clean this up but unsure of the best practice for compiling a list of variables and still separating them on individual lines on the .txt file they're being copied to.

This is my first post here.

I've recently created a script to automate an extremely tedious process at work that involves modifying an excel document, copying and pasting outputs from specifics cells depending on the type of configuration we are generating and pasting into 3 separate .txt files to send out via email.

I've got the script functioning, but I hate how my code looks and to be honest, it is quite the pain to try to make additions to.

I'm using openpyxl & pycel for this, as the cells I copy are outputs from a formula that I couldn't seem to get anything except for #N/A when strictly using openpyxl so I integrated pycel for that piece.

I've referenced my code below, & I appreciate any input.

```
            F62 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F62'))
            F63 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F63'))
            F64 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F64'))
            F65 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F65'))
            F66 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F66'))
            F67 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F67'))
            F68 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F68'))
            F69 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F69'))
            F70 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F70'))
            F71 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F71'))
            F72 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F72'))
            F73 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F73'))
            F74 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F74'))
            F75 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F75'))
            F76 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F76'))
            F77 = format(excel.evaluate('Config!F77'))
            #so on and so forth to put into:

with open(f'./GRAK-R-{KIT}/3_GRAK-R-{KIT}_FULL.txt', 'r') as basedone:
            linetest = f"{F62}\n{F63}\n{F64}\n{F65}\n{F66}\n{F67}\n{F68}\n{F69}\n{F70}\n{F71}\n{F72}\n{F73}\n{F74}\n{F75}\n{F76}\n{F77}\n{F78}\n{F79}\n{F80}\n{F81}\n{F82}\n{F83}\n{F84}\n{F85}\n{F86}\n{F87}\n{F88}\n{F89}\n{F90}\n{F91}\n{F92}\n{F93}\n{F94}\n{F95}\n{F96}\n{F97}\n{F98}\n{F99}\n{F100}\n{F101}\n{F102}\n{F103}\n{F104}\n{F105}\n{F106}\n{F107}\n{F108}\n{F109}\n{F110}\n{F111}\n{F112}\n{F113}\n{F114}\n{F115}\n{F116}\n{F117}\n{F118}\n{F119}\n{F120}\n{F121}\n{F122}\n{F123}\n{F124}\n{F125}\n{F126}\n{F127}\n{F128}\n{F129}\n{F130}\n{F131}\n{F132}\n{F133}\n{F134}\n{F135}\n{F136}\n{F137}\n{F138}\n{F139}\n{F140}\n{F141}\n{F142}\n{F143}\n{F144}\n{F145}\n{F146}\n{F147}\n{F148}\n{F149}\n{F150}\n{F151}\n{F152}\n{F153}\n{F154}\n{F155}\n{F156}\n{F157}\n{F158}\n{F159}\n{F160}\n{F161}\n{F162}\n{F163}\n{F164}\n{F165}\n{F166}\n{F167}\n{F168}\n{F169}\n{F170}\n{F171}\n{F172}\n{F173}\n{F174}\n{F175}\n{F176}\n{F177}\n{F178}\n{F179}\n {F180}\n{F181}\{F182}\n{F183}\n{F184}\n{F185}\n{F186}\n{F187}\n{F188}\n{F189}\n{F190}\n {F191}\n{F192}\n{F193}\n{F194}\n{F195}\n{F196}\n{F197}\n{F198}\n{F199}\n{F200}\n{F201}\n{F202}\n{F203}\n{F204}\n{F205}\n{F206}\n{F207}\n{F208}\n{F209}\n{F210}\n{F211}\n{F212}\n{F213}\n{F214}\n{F215}\n{F216}\n{F217}\n{F218}\n{F219}\n{F220}\n{F221}\n{F222}\n{F223}\n{F224}\n{F225}\n{F226}\n{F227}\n{F228}\n{F229}\n{F230}\n{F231}\n{F232}\n{F233}\n{F234}\n{F235}\n{F236}\n{F237}\n{F238}\n{F239}\n{F240}\n{F241}\n{F242}\n{F243}\n{F244}\n{F245}\n{F246}\n{F247}\n{F248}\n{F249}\n{F250}\n{F251}\n{F252}\n{F253}\n{F254}\n{F255}\n{F256}\n{F257}\n{F258}\n{F259}\n{F260}\n{F261}\n{F262}\n{F263}\n{F264}\n{F265}\n{F266}\n{F267}\n{F268}\n{F269}\n{F270}\n{F271}\n{F272}\n{F273}\n{F274}\n"
            oline = basedone.readlines()
            oline.insert(9,linetest)
            basedone.close()

        with open(f'./GRAK-R-{KIT}/3_GRAK-R-{KIT}_FULL.txt', 'w') as basedone:
            basedone.writelines(oline)
            basedone.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to name every single variable. You can use `f-strings` and `list comprehensions` to keep your code flexible.

```
min_cell = 62
max_cell = 77
column_name = 'F'
sheet_name = 'Config'

cell_names = [f'{sheet_name}!{column_name}{i}' for i in range(min_cell, max_cell + 1)]
vals = [format(excel.evaluate(cn)) for cn in cell_names] 
linetest = '\n'.join(vals)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this would have saved me soooo much time first go around! I really appreciate the respone!